# Looping back to the top of Python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Would you be able to assist a newbie here with a small Python script?

Editing my question. As the below code worked for what it was intended.

Now what I am trying to achieve is that i also have a second script. (posted below) That controls a PIR Sensor which ALSO turns the light on.
But I would like to try and merge the two scripts into 1 single script.

It should as default use the PIR sensor to turn the light on when movement is detected. But! If the button is pushed it should override the sensor and leave the light on for 15 minutes.

As I have it set up now the pir does its job. But if there is no movement in front of it and I push the button it turns the light on then quickly off again as the pir is detecting no movement.

Both scripts below. All help I can get is very very much appreciated.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)         #Read output from PIR motion sensor
while True:
   i=GPIO.input(4)
   if i==0:                 #When output from motion sensor is LOW
         print "No movement detected - Turning lights off",i
         exec(open("./LightsOff.py").read(), globals())
         time.sleep(0.1)
   elif i==1:               #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
         print "Movement detected - Turning lights on",i
         exec(open("./LightsOn.py").read(), globals())
         time.sleep(60 * 15)


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
input_state = GPIO.input(18)
if input_state == False:
    print('Button Pressed')
    execfile("LightsOn.py")
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try to figure it out? =) I think it would work but testing will clear any doubts. By the way, instead of `exec(open(...))` other python modules, I would rather join them in a single file e.g. `lights.py`, then `ìmport lights` and call `on()` and `off()` functions,

Comment: Did run a test on it and it did the job. So thanks for that. Joining them in a single file is now my mission

Answer (score 0):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
starttime = 0
while True:
    if GPIO.input(18) == False and starttime == 0:
        #waiting for release button
        while not GPIO.input(18):
            pass
        starttime = time.time()
        print('Turning on Kitchen Lights for 15 minutes')
        exec(open('LightsOn.py').read())
    if (time.time() - starttime) < (15*60) and starttime != 0 and GPIO.input(18) == False:
        #waiting for release button
        while not GPIO.input(18):
            pass
        exec(open('LightsOff.py').read())
        starttime=0           

    if (time.time() - starttime) > (15*60) and starttime != 0:
        exec(open('LightsOff.py').read())
        starttime=0
```

You can use time.time() function for timings.

Also you can use time.sleep(0.1) at the end of the while loop for decreasing cpu load

Script should work.

Comment: Also if u have anymore input on the edited question id really appreciate it.